# angular 8 i have problem in sending id in angular

Tags: html, angular

i am using angular 8 as front end and flask as backend. this a page to show all products on button click navigate to the specific product page and id have to be pass through url but it is not working properly
my code is given below

html

```
          <div class="grid-offer">
            <div class="row" >
              <div class="col-md-2 col-6 col-sm-4" style=" margin-bottom: 1em;" *ngFor="let item of product| slice:0:24;"> <br>
                <div class="box" routerLink="item">
                  <img [src]="item.photo" alt="image slide" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <h6>{{item.name}}</h6>           
                    <h6>MRP : ₹ {{item.price}}</h6>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-left: .1em; margin-right: .1em;">
                      <div class="col">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btnborder" id="{{item.pId}}" (click)=buy($event)><i class="fa fa-money fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" ></i></button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-orange btnborder" id="{{item.pId}}" (click)=addToCart($event)><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

ts

```
  buy(event){
    console.log("item",event.target.id);
    this.commonService.instantBuy(event.target.id).subscribe((data:any)=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.route.navigate(['productdetails'])
    })    
  }
```

service

```
  public instantBuy(data:any){
    return this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/getproductbyid",data);
  }
```

when clicking button id is passing but this error is coming..

```
item 1
```

**Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'item' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'item'**

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing `$event` on click `(click)="buy($event)"`, pass the the whole `item` `(click)="buy(item)"`

#### app.component.html

```html
...
<div class="col">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btnborder" id="{{item.pId}}" (click)="buy(item)"><i class="fa fa-money fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" ></i></button>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-orange btnborder" id="{{item.pId}}" (click)="addToCart(item)"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
...
```

#### app.component.ts

```
buy(item){
  console.log(item.pId);       
}
```

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'item' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'item'

Comment: @NrJ That error has to do with your routing.  Where does that error occur?